# How can I change the transform: translate() position of an element as one scrolls through a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, transform

I'm kind of new to this and couldn't find any solutions so far that works.

I want to achieve the effect present on the images here: http://www.apple.com/macbook/

When the user scrolls down, the image is going up and vice versa. I took a look into their javascript files (line 28928 in overview.build.js), found the lines that do this but couldn't understood it exactly.

On my website when I want to use this effect I have the image inside a div container as img tag, but I can also place it as background-image.

Thank you for yor time!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are referring to is a parallax effect. There are a wide variety of jQuery plugins to achieve this effect. 
The plugin that I use: 
https://github.com/jalxob/cool-kitten
You can find tons of other options by googling "parallax effect"